# SvelteKit: Auth.js & Graph SDK - where to auth and call the API?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, sveltekit, next-auth, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am currently trying to make API calls to MS Graph via Graph SDK. For Auth I used Auth.js, which works fine.

Using tutorials and other articles I intend to use getToken() to init a Client instance and use Client.api to make the calls.

But where should I initiate that Client?

In another attempt I managed to auth in +page.server.js via @azure/identity and make the API calls, in the current attempt I auth within hooks.server.js - thus I can also restrict access to certain routes.

The question is: auth & calls from +page.server.js or from hooks.server.js?

If you'd like I can provide both codes - it was a hassle to get it working.

Currently attempting to set the Client up in +layout.server.js - not sure if it's working...

Comment: Check https://www.reddit.com/r/sveltejs/comments/17o7fco/azuread_graph_sdk_where_to_auth_call_the_apis/ and https://medium.com/@uriser/authentication-in-sveltekit-with-auth-js-7ff505d584c4

Comment: Funny: That reddit post is mine (I'm DunklerErpel on reddit) - but cheers for looking for it!